# there are two @Bean in a class with @configuration. but I need that in a case take a @Bean and other case take the other one

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I have this configuration.
when i run the aplication. java take the @Primary Bean but i need that in a specific case take @Bean (name = "INA")

```
@Configuration @RequiredArgsConstructor public class RestConsumerConfig { private static final String TLS = "TLSv1.2";

private final SecretsManager secretManager;
private final S3AsynOperations s3AsynOperations;
private final AwsProperties awsProperties;


@Bean
@Primary
public WebClient webClientConfig(final ConsumerProperties consumerProperties) {
    System.out.println("config MAS");
    return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(clientHttpConnectorWithSsl(consumerProperties.getTimeout()))
            .defaultHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .defaultHeader(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "INA")
@Autowired
public WebClient webClientConfigIna(final ConsumerProperties consumerProperties) {
    System.out.println("config INA");
    return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(clientHttpConnectorWithoutSsl(consumerProperties.getTimeout()))
            .defaultHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .defaultHeader(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
}

}
```

i try created a RestConsumerConfig object with  @Qualifier("INA") but that one no take @Bean(name="INA")

Comment: Have you looked at Spring profiles? If I understand what you are trying to do correctly having switchable http and https profiles is probably what you want.

Comment: Hi friend I am using spring profiles in other class configuration. but i don´t know how switching between @Profiles while the code is running. Do you know?

Comment: Profiles are no good for changing things at runtime. The issue with what you are doing above is that you apply the `@Qualifier` to the injection point of the `WebClient` bean not the configuration bean.

Comment: @HopeyOne I inyected the Bean https://gist.github.com/rbecerrav/799fb69b0795364202a5aa374abe1a0e in the gist i have de code where I use the BEan with Qualifier but I not sure.I need delete the if and else. i need use a webclient.post not two.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem with what you are doing in the gist.